# How to merge two api in python by id in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a dictionary with using 2 api. Can you guide me?
I want to create a dictionary with using 2 api. Can you guide me?

```
url = 'https://test.com/api/v1/'
tags = []
result=[]
    
response = requests.get(url)
results = json.loads(response.text)

for data in results['results']:
```

second API

```
url = 'https://test.com/api/v1/'+data['tags_id']

response = requests.get(url)
results = json.loads(response.text)


for data in results['tags']:
    tags.append(data['title'])
```

result of first api

```
    results: [
            {
              "title": "subject1",
              "tags_id": "86111ae6",
     },
            {
              "title": "subject2",
              "tags_id": "86ae6",
     }]
```

expected result

```
    results: [
            {
              "title": "subject1",
              "tags: ['a','b'],
     },
            {
              "title": "subject2",
              "tags": ['c','d','f'],
     }]
```

second API

```
  "tags": [
    {
   "title": 'a',
    },
    {
   "title": 'b',
    },
  ]
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? Your question in unclear

Comment: I can not create the expected dictionary using data['tags_id']

Comment: What means "I can not do this through the ID"? What happens? Does the second API not support what you want?

Comment: I want to get the tags list with data['tags_id'] form first api

Comment: We can't run your code. So you have to be much more clear. What does your second API give you? What is the json response from your second API for a specific tag?

Comment: The first api gives tags_id that I shows with data['tags_id'] then I put it in second API to get name of tags @not_speshal

Comment: The tags for "subject1" and "subject2" are exactly the same (=86ae6). How do you expect to get different tags from the same url?

Comment: Post the response from the second API for a specific tag. For example, use "86ae6", and show us the `response.json`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237574/discussion-between-user12217822-and-not-speshal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each "title" from the first API has exactly one "tags_id", I think what you want is something like:

```
url = 'https://test.com/api/v1/'
response = requests.get(url)
results = json.loads(response.text)

output = list()
for d in results['results']:
    response = requests.get(f'https://test.com/api/v1/{d["tags_id"]}/show_tags')
    result = json.loads(response.text)
    output.append({"title": d["title"], 
                   "tags": [t["title"] for t in result["tags"]]})
```

Comment: But this code only works for one element, not an array @not_speshal

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: The resulit is: [{'title': 'subject1
  'tags': [
   'a',
   'b']}]    without subject 2

Comment: I am using `for d in results["results"]` so you should be getting everything that's in `results["results"]`. Check the output you posted for API1